# In metro, what's the difference between FolderInformation and StorageFolder

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

`FolderInformation`'s methods/properties are nearly the same with `StorageFolder`'s.
 I can't figure out why WinRT api provides `FolderInformation` and `StorageFolder` as well. If I assign the list created from `FileInformationFactory.GetFoldersAsync()` to an `ItemsControl`, does it differ from the listed created from `StorageFolder.CreateFolderAsync()` ?
The document says the `FolderInformation` provides synchronous access, but I don't know when the issue would happen.

The one drawback I found in `FolderInformation` is it could only be created from `FileInformationFactory`. So I think it's impossible to create a `FolderInformation` for the `KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FolderInformation lets you act on the Folder itself (as in move it, delete it, rename it etc.)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.bulkaccess.folderinformation.aspx

Whereas StorageFolder lets you act on the contents of the folder (as in create a new file in the folder, create a new sub-folder in the folder, get all the files from the folder etc.)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.aspx

Comment: This saying doesn't make sense when they both have the method, `CreateFileAsync()`. But this saying makes sense when only `FolderInformation` has the Event members. However, if there is any hack to get the `FolderInformation` for the `KnownFolders.XXXLibrary`, it's perfect.